# AWS Elasticsearch Service: How do you remove cluster create_index block?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I initially thought the block was automatically put in place because my cluster health was yellow. I read up on shard optimization, saw that I had many unassigned shards. I increased the node count to 2 and it went green.

```
GET /_cluster/health?level=indices
```

```
{
  "cluster_name" : "861156488073:hd-staging",
  "status" : "green",
  "timed_out" : false,
  "number_of_nodes" : 2,
  "number_of_data_nodes" : 2,
  "discovered_master" : true,
  "active_primary_shards" : 47,
  "active_shards" : 94,
  "relocating_shards" : 0,
  "initializing_shards" : 0,
  "unassigned_shards" : 0,
  "delayed_unassigned_shards" : 0,
  "number_of_pending_tasks" : 0,
  "number_of_in_flight_fetch" : 0,
  "task_max_waiting_in_queue_millis" : 0,
  "active_shards_percent_as_number" : 100.0,
  "indices" : {
    ".kibana_-1326395655_honestdoorstg_1" : {
      "status" : "green",
      "number_of_shards" : 1,
      "number_of_replicas" : 1,
      "active_primary_shards" : 1,
      "active_shards" : 2,
      "relocating_shards" : 0,
      "initializing_shards" : 0,
      "unassigned_shards" : 0
    },
    ".kibana_-1326395655_honestdoorstg_2" : {
      "status" : "green",
      "number_of_shards" : 1,
      "number_of_replicas" : 1,
      "active_primary_shards" : 1,
      "active_shards" : 2,
      "relocating_shards" : 0,
      "initializing_shards" : 0,
      "unassigned_shards" : 0
    },
    ".kibana_2" : {
      "status" : "green",
      "number_of_shards" : 1,
      "number_of_replicas" : 1,
      "active_primary_shards" : 1,
      "active_shards" : 2,
      "relocating_shards" : 0,
      "initializing_shards" : 0,
      "unassigned_shards" : 0
    },
    "neighbourhood_assessment" : {
      "status" : "green",
      "number_of_shards" : 5,
      "number_of_replicas" : 1,
      "active_primary_shards" : 5,
      "active_shards" : 10,
      "relocating_shards" : 0,
      "initializing_shards" : 0,
      "unassigned_shards" : 0
    },
    ".kibana_1" : {
      "status" : "green",
      "number_of_shards" : 1,
      "number_of_replicas" : 1,
      "active_primary_shards" : 1,
      "active_shards" : 2,
      "relocating_shards" : 0,
      "initializing_shards" : 0,
      "unassigned_shards" : 0
    },
    ".opendistro_security" : {
      "status" : "green",
      "number_of_shards" : 1,
      "number_of_replicas" : 1,
      "active_primary_shards" : 1,
      "active_shards" : 2,
      "relocating_shards" : 0,
      "initializing_shards" : 0,
      "unassigned_shards" : 0
    },
    ".tasks" : {
      "status" : "green",
      "number_of_shards" : 1,
      "number_of_replicas" : 1,
      "active_primary_shards" : 1,
      "active_shards" : 2,
      "relocating_shards" : 0,
      "initializing_shards" : 0,
      "unassigned_shards" : 0
    },
    ".kibana_3" : {
      "status" : "green",
      "number_of_shards" : 1,
      "number_of_replicas" : 1,
      "active_primary_shards" : 1,
      "active_shards" : 2,
      "relocating_shards" : 0,
      "initializing_shards" : 0,
      "unassigned_shards" : 0
    },
    "assessment" : {
      "status" : "green",
      "number_of_shards" : 5,
      "number_of_replicas" : 1,
      "active_primary_shards" : 5,
      "active_shards" : 10,
      "relocating_shards" : 0,
      "initializing_shards" : 0,
      "unassigned_shards" : 0
    },
    "valuation" : {
      "status" : "green",
      "number_of_shards" : 5,
      "number_of_replicas" : 1,
      "active_primary_shards" : 5,
      "active_shards" : 10,
      "relocating_shards" : 0,
      "initializing_shards" : 0,
      "unassigned_shards" : 0
    },
    "neighbourhood" : {
      "status" : "green",
      "number_of_shards" : 5,
      "number_of_replicas" : 1,
      "active_primary_shards" : 5,
      "active_shards" : 10,
      "relocating_shards" : 0,
      "initializing_shards" : 0,
      "unassigned_shards" : 0
    },
    "permit" : {
      "status" : "green",
      "number_of_shards" : 5,
      "number_of_replicas" : 1,
      "active_primary_shards" : 5,
      "active_shards" : 10,
      "relocating_shards" : 0,
      "initializing_shards" : 0,
      "unassigned_shards" : 0
    },
    "property" : {
      "status" : "green",
      "number_of_shards" : 5,
      "number_of_replicas" : 1,
      "active_primary_shards" : 5,
      "active_shards" : 10,
      "relocating_shards" : 0,
      "initializing_shards" : 0,
      "unassigned_shards" : 0
    },
    "listing" : {
      "status" : "green",
      "number_of_shards" : 5,
      "number_of_replicas" : 1,
      "active_primary_shards" : 5,
      "active_shards" : 10,
      "relocating_shards" : 0,
      "initializing_shards" : 0,
      "unassigned_shards" : 0
    },
    "close" : {
      "status" : "green",
      "number_of_shards" : 5,
      "number_of_replicas" : 1,
      "active_primary_shards" : 5,
      "active_shards" : 10,
      "relocating_shards" : 0,
      "initializing_shards" : 0,
      "unassigned_shards" : 0
    }
  }
}
```

But the block remains:

```
GET /_cluster/settings
```

```
{
  "persistent" : {
    "cluster" : {
      "routing" : {
        "allocation" : {
          "cluster_concurrent_rebalance" : "2",
          "node_concurrent_recoveries" : "2",
          "disk" : {
            "watermark" : {
              "low" : "1.35gb",
              "flood_stage" : "0.45gb",
              "high" : "0.9gb"
            }
          },
          "node_initial_primaries_recoveries" : "4"
        }
      },
      "blocks" : {
        "create_index" : "true"
      }
    },
    "indices" : {
      "recovery" : {
        "max_bytes_per_sec" : "60mb"
      }
    }
  },
  "transient" : {
    "cluster" : {
      "routing" : {
        "allocation" : {
          "cluster_concurrent_rebalance" : "2",
          "node_concurrent_recoveries" : "2",
          "disk" : {
            "watermark" : {
              "low" : "1.35gb",
              "flood_stage" : "0.45gb",
              "high" : "0.9gb"
            }
          },
          "exclude" : { },
          "node_initial_primaries_recoveries" : "4"
        }
      }
    },
    "indices" : {
      "recovery" : {
        "max_bytes_per_sec" : "60mb"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I've tried using the _cluster/settings API with all of:

```
PUT /_cluster/settings
{"persistent": {"cluster": {"blocks.create_index": (null and false)}}}

PUT /_cluster/settings
{"persistent": {"cluster.blocks": (null and false)}}

PUT /_cluster/settings
{
  "persistent" : {
    "cluster.blocks.create_index": (null and false)
  }
}
# all return
{"Message":"Your request: '/_cluster/settings' payload is not allowed."}
```

How do I clear that block so I can re-index? Are the persistent settings even editable on Elasticsearch Service? What am I missing?

I think increasing my domain to 2 nodes pushed me to capacity storage on the EBS allocation:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/aes-handling-errors.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The disk space on the instance was the issue. ‍♂️

A very handy tool for shard optimization, so you don't run into this problem:
https://gbaptista.github.io/elastic-calculator/